# Uploading Symbol files for Android NDK crash reports automatically

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I am using Crashlytic sdk for collecting Android NDK crash reports. Please find the configuration file below.

It works well if I run the following command:
`./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsXXXRelease`

Also, If I add `assembleXXXRelease.finalizedBy(crashlyticsUploadSymbolsXXXRelease)` to `afterEvaluate` block, the symbol files also are uploaded after each build.

#### Here are my questions:

1. I want this uploading process to be automatic. The issue I am facing is the finalizedBy way will added around 10 more minutes to the build time, which is I have to avoid. I prefer to create a new task and invoke it somewhere else after each build, so the APK build time will stay the same as now. I tried to do so, but it seems not working. See the code below. If you have any clue or I missed something, please let me know.
2. Is that possible to override the NDK output path based on different flavor? I tried to get the flavor XXX from task name like assbleXXXRelease, and assign it to the output path like XXX/obj, but failed. It seems the flavor has been fixed to the default flavor.
3. Is that possible that I can pick up the cSYM symbols files and upload to Crashlytics without Crashlytic sdk?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

// Question 2 will be happening here:
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut "obj" // override the path based on the flavor name to flavorName/obj?
    androidNdkLibsOut "libs" // override the path based on the flavor name to flavorName/libs?
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    // Add the Crashlytics NDK dependency
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.1.1'
}

// Question 1 will be happening here:
// If I call this task from command line, it won't work. Nothing will happen.
task upload {
    doLast {
        crashlyticsUploadSymbolsXXXRelease
    }
}

afterEvaluate {project ->
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        assembleXXXRelease.finalizedBy(crashlyticsUploadSymbolsXXXRelease) // it works here
    }
}
```

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I want this uploading process to be automatic. The issue I am facing is the finalizedBy way will added around 10 more minutes to the build time, which is I have to avoid. I prefer to create a new task and invoke it somewhere else after each build, so the APK build time will stay the same as now. I tried to do so, but it seems not working.

I solved this by modifying the task as follows:

```
task upload {
    doLast {
       // do something whatever
    }
}

upload.finalizedBy(crashlyticsUploadSymbolsXXXRelease)
```

> 2. Is that possible to override the NDK output path based on different flavor? I tried to get the flavor XXX from task name like assbleXXXRelease, and assign it to the output path like XXX/obj, but failed. It seems the flavor has been fixed to the default flavor.

I have made this work to get the current flavor name by calling

```
gradle.startParameter.taskName[0]
```

> 3. Is that possible that I can pick up the cSYM symbols files and upload to Crashlytics without Crashlytic sdk?

I have not yet found a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I want this uploading process to be automatic. The issue I am facing is the finalizedBy way will added around 10 more minutes to the build time, which is I have to avoid. I prefer to create a new task and invoke it somewhere else after each build, so the APK build time will stay the same as now.

I created a Gradle project that allows exactly that: uploading Firebase Crashlytics NDK symbols independent from the build process of your app.

You can check it out here:
https://github.com/triplef/android-upload-ndk-symbols